# Building LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, graph, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get my layout to look like this:

[image]

My class containing this code extends Linelayout itself and adds the different elements with addView

```
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        LinearLayout line = new LinearLayout(context);
    line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    viewVerLabels = new VerLabelsView(context);

            // add y axis linearlayout & graphview
    line.addView(viewVerLabels);
    line.addView(new GraphViewContentView(context), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    line.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // add to main linearlayout
    addView(line);

    LinearLayout line2 = new LinearLayout(context);
    line2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    viewHorLabels = new HorLabelsView(context);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            // add x axis labels
    line2.addView(viewHorLabels);
            // add to main linearlayout
    addView(line2);
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/graph2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

With this code I get the Y axis labels and the graph to appear, but the X axis labels are missing

I can't seem to get what I want, I've tried several combinations, what am I doing wrong

Comment: Create in designer your layout template, then create in code objects with same params and sequence like in designer

Comment: I just tried that, I also tried replacing my views with buttons just to see it it gave me the layout I want
With the buttons it gives me what I want but with my views no

Comment: I am not sure about it. But you are using android:layout_height="250dp" for main linear layout graph2. Try to put linear layout inside scrollview.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a graphing library like [achartengine](http://achartengine.org)?

Comment: I'm trying to get the graph to look as close as I can to the iPhone version of the app, which looks like this, http://postimage.org/image/ld4e8pvq9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code that allowed me to get round the problem

```
        graphViewStyle = new GraphViewStyle();
        paint = new Paint();
        graphSeries = new ArrayList<GraphViewSeries>();

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout line = new LinearLayout(context);
        line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        line.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout line2 = new LinearLayout(context);
        line2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        line2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        txt = new TextView(mContext);
        addView(txt);

        GraphViewContentView graphContentView = new GraphViewContentView(context);
        graphContentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 260, 1));
        line.addView(graphContentView);
        viewVerLabels = new VerLabelsView(context);
        viewVerLabels.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 260));
        viewHorLabels = new HorLabelsView(context);
        viewHorLabels.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 15));

        line.addView(viewVerLabels);

        addView(line);

        line2.addView(viewHorLabels);
        TextView v = new TextView(context);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 15));
        line2.addView(v);

        addView(line2);
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a size issue where when adding the first Layouts to the parent, they fill up the entire area and the others are just now shown.

As other mentions, recommendations (I would try either one independent)
- A scroll View in top of everything.
- Create a separate Control that extends from LinearLayout with its respective layout.xml that just inflates inside. And on this Activity when showing just instantiate this control and add just one Layout that has them all.
- Create a New LinearLayout in top of everything, add all to it and then add that one to the actual View.

If any work or you got a solution post it so others can see and benefit.

Comment: I have managed to work around my problem with fixed width rather than with wrap_content which I don't really like because it's not a very clean way of coding and may not be completely correct, but for the moment I don't have the time to try and implement the new suggestions but as soon as I do I will post it and give credit to the person whose works the best

Answer (score 1):

Hi just try this code I have changed some values, views and setBackground to colors, it gives same output as you desire.

LinearLayout MLayoutTm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph2);

```
    LinearLayout line = new LinearLayout(this);
    line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 1));
    line.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    TextView viewVerLabels = new TextView(this);

    viewVerLabels.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    viewVerLabels.setText("Nimsih");
    viewVerLabels.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    line.addView(viewVerLabels);

    TextView GraphViewContentView = new TextView(this);
    GraphViewContentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    GraphViewContentView.setText("Nimsih2");
    GraphViewContentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
    line.addView(GraphViewContentView);

    line.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    MLayoutTm.addView(line);

    LinearLayout line2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    line2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    line2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView viewHorLabels = new TextView(this);
    viewHorLabels.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            1));
    viewHorLabels.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    viewHorLabels.setText("Nimsih3 ");

    MLayoutTm.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    line2.addView(viewHorLabels);

    MLayoutTm.addView(line2);
```

Comment: not working, I don't know whether it's because the graph and labels are linelayouts

Comment: you can replace the text-view in above example with linearLayout to check that.

Comment: sorry I meant to say views, however I have already chenged the textviews into views but I get a Cyan colored screen (the horizontal labels) with this code

Comment: yes please remove all the setBackgroundColor methods, they were used for representation purpose.

Comment: I know however, that shouldn't affect the layout itself

Comment: Also try to set your custom layout content, to match_parent. Also try to replace the 3 text views with linear layout and add your view in those layouts. ( rather then replacing the textviews with custom view)

Answer (score 1):

i am acheving x-axis lable and y-axis lable by using code of arnodenhond. you can get from 
http://android.arnodenhond.com/components

my emulator screen shot [image]

Comment: I had a look at his GraphView and it seems quite light, I need quite a few features, to make it look as close as I can to the iPhone app which looks like this http://postimage.org/image/ld4e8pvq9/, I don't think this library allows you to paint a background easily.

Answer (score 1):

try to set different background colors to the layouts you created to see their real areas. Most likely some layouts occupied all the available height so the X axis labels are out the border.
You may want to assign some kind of weight for the layouts, like the total weight sum as 5, assign 4 for the drawing area and set 1 to the layout that holds the X-axis labels